# Class test for Trigger to match a field in object A with object b and populate a relationship lookup in b

Tags: trigger, unit-test, class

I need some help to create a test class to validate the trigger down, someone help me? I do not know where to start, I've tried to get some example and build the class but I could not, yet

```
Trigger updateContatoPonto on Ponto__c (before insert, before update) {

// build a set of receivable Inscricao_Numero__c
Set <Decimal> receberInscricaoNumero = new Set <Decimal> ();

for(Ponto__c pontos : trigger.New)
{
    receberInscricaoNumero.add(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c);
}

// Map the contacts Inscricao_Numero__c and the actual contacts records based on the receivable Inscricao_Numero__c
Map <Decimal, Contact> matchingcontactsMap = new Map <Decimal, Contact> ();
for (Contact contacts : [Select Id, Inscricao_Numero__c From Contact Where Inscricao_Numero__c IN :receberInscricaoNumero])
{
    matchingcontactsMap.put(contacts.Inscricao_Numero__c, contacts);
}

List <Ponto__c> receivablesToUpdate = new List <Ponto__c> ();
for(Ponto__c pontos : trigger.New)
{
    if (matchingcontactsMap.get(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c) != null)
    {
       pontos.Contato__c = matchingcontactsMap.get(pontos.Inscricao_Numero__c).Id;
    } 
    else {
            pontos.Contato__c = null;
        }
} 
update receivablesToUpdate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to create data in your test class to cover the trigger. Since you wont have access to data in sandbox, you have to create Ponto__c and contact records.

As the trigger fires on before and after insert events on ponto__c object, the trigger is covered when you create ponto__c records in test class.

Use the following code as reference,

```
    @isTest
    private class testTrigger {

        static testmethod void executeTriggerTest(){

            Account testAcc = new Account(Name = 'testaccount',AccountNumber = '123');
            insert testAcc;

            List<contact> testContactsList = new List<Contact>();

            for(integer i=0;i<3;i++){
                testContactsList.add(new contact(FirstName='test', LastName ='contact'+i,Inscricao_Numero__c = i));
            }
            insert testContactsList;

            Ponto__c testPonto = new Ponto__c(name= 'testnameponto',Inscricao_Numero__c = 2);
            insert testPonto;

//code to cover the else for 100% coverage
Ponto__c Pontonew = new Ponto__c(name= 'testnameponto');
            insert Pontonew ;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Now i recieve this error --Invalid initial expression type for field Account, expecting: Account (or single row query result of that type)

Comment: which line number?

Comment: 12  testContactsList.add(new contact(account=testAcc.id,Name='testcontact'+i,Inscricao_Numero__c = i));

Comment: I have updated my code,please try that once

Comment: keep... line 12,

Comment: Is it still throwing error?

Comment: Yes, in line testContactsList.add(new contact(account=testAcc.id,FirstName='test', LastName ='contact'+i,Inscricao_Numero__c = i));

Comment: Inscricao_Numero__c is decimal (10,0), I changed, but the error persists.

Comment: can you try it now, i updated the code in answer

Comment: I will try, wait a minute

Comment: Hi, to finish 100% coverage, how i can test this code? else {
            pontos.Contato__c = null;

Comment: its possible ? @Anurag

Comment: Yes, i have updated the code, please try  that

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do `update receivablesToUpdate;` you pretty much just hijacking the values before it gets inserted/updated

But there are a ton of tutorials, what have you tried?

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm

Comment: Thank you for the informations,
It happens that I am not a developer, so I could not understand how well create the class,
But I keep trying. If you can help with a more complete example, I will be able to adapt,
Thank you